# Why do these two functions in Haskell have the same type?

Tags: function, haskell, types

I am working through Graham Hutton's *Programming in Haskell*, and an exercise in Chapter 3 asks "What is the type?" for the function `twice f x = f (f x)`.

I think I understand why the answer is `twice :: (t -> t) -> t -> t`. (**Edit**: I did *not* understand why. See my comment on Paolo's answer.)  However, to experiment I  wrote another function `thrice f x = f (f (f x))`.

What I definitely *don't* understand is why `thrice` also has a type of `thrice :: (t -> t) -> t -> t`.

They work the way I would expect (see below), but I can't see how the type of `thrice` makes sense.

From `ghci`:

```
>> twice tail [0,1,2,3,4]
[2,3,4]
>> thrice tail [0,1,2,3,4]
[3,4]
```

Comment: Just try to visualize "what goes in" and "what goes out". The nesting of the functions doesn't change any of that.

Comment: (t -> t) -> t -> t can be understood as a function that take as parametter a (t -> t) function, a t element and return a t, which is the case for twice and thrice. In your example t is instancied as [Int]. tail goes from [a] -> [a], [0,1,2,3,4] is of type [Int], the result is also of type [Int].

Comment: In fact [0,1,2,3,4] is of type Num t => [t], meaning a list of numerical values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, maybe I don't understand your question, but if you look at your own example with list, you'll see that in both twice and thrice's case, the inputs are a function from list to list (`tail`) and a list (`[0,1,2,3,4]`) and the return type is a list.

So both `twice` and `thrice` match the signature `(t -> t) -> t -> t`: a function from t to t (in your case `tail`), a t (in your case a list) and another t (list) in return

Comment: My question was probably unclear, because I was confused about exactly what the type of a function shows. I half thought that the signature should reflect the *steps* that the function itself went through. So I expected `thrice` to need *another*  `-> t` in its signature. Thanks for clarifying (to me even) where I was confused.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps it's easier to see point-free:

```
twice f = f . f
thrice f = f . f . f
```

so you compose `f` with itself a few times. To be able to compose `f` with itself, the result of applying `f` to an argument must have suitable type, so that `f` in turn can be applied to that. Now if you start with

```
f :: a -> r     -- argument type -> result type
```

the suitability condition means that `r` must match `a`. For type variables that means `r = a`. Thus, `twice` as well as `thrice` take a function from some type to the same type and return a function from that type to the same,

```
twice :: (a -> a) -> (a -> a)
thrice :: (a -> a) -> (a -> a)
```

Since the function-type arrow is right associative (`x -> y -> z = x -> (y -> z)`, the last parentheses in the type can be omitted.

Comment: I'm not yet familiar with point-free style, but thanks for the explanation in other terms.

Answer (score 4):

The type of *twice* states that *twice* is a function from a function with domain *a* and codomain *a* to a function with domain *a* and codomain *a*. The type of *thrice* states that *thrice* is a function from a function with domain *a* and codomain *a* to a function with domain *a* and codomain *a*.

To see why, consider a derivation of the type of *twice* and *thrice*. Given a function *f* : *a* → *a* and variable *x*, the rule for determining the type of *f* (*f x*) states that we must first determine the types of of *f* and *(f x)*, then apply the rule for function application. The rule for determining the type of *(f x)* states that we must first determine the type of *f* and *x*, then apply the rule for function application.

First, since *f* has type *a* → *a* and *x* has type *a*, the rule for function application states that (*f x*) has type *a*. Since *f* has type *a* → *a* and (*f x*) has type *a*, the rule for function application states that *f* (*f x*) has type *a*. An additional application of the rule for function application gives *f* (*f* (*f x*)) has type *a*. As you see, repeated application of the rule for application gives *f*<sup>n</sup> *x* will have type *a* for all *n* ∈ ℕ.

Second, the rule for function abstraction states that if *x* : *τ*, *M* : *τ'* and *x* does not occur free in *M*, then the abstraction λ *x* : *τ* . *M* has type *τ* → *τ'*. We have terms *f* (*f x*) and *f* (*f* (*f x*)) both with type *a* and a variable *x* with type *a*. Hence, the abstractions λ *x* : *a* . *f* (*f x*) and λ *x* : *a* . *f* (*f* (*f x*)) both have type *a* → *a*. Finally, since *f* : *a* → *a*, applying the rule for function abstraction once more gives λ *f* : *a* → *a* . λ *x* : *a* . *f* (*f x*) and λ *f* : *a* → *a* . λ *x* : *a* . *f* (*f* (*f x*)) have type (*a* → *a*) → (*a* → *a*).

As you can see, Haskell's type system is too inexpressive to state that *twice* applies a function *f* to an argument *x* two times whereas *thrice* applies a function *f* to an argument *x* three times. What it *can* express is that both *twice* and *thrice* accept a function as input and return a function from a term *x* to a term *y* both of type *a*. This function is λ *x* : *a* . *f* (*f x*) for *twice* and λ *x* : *a* . *f* (*f* (*f x*)) for *thrice*.

I would suggest reading a short introduction to the polymorphic λ-calculus, which Haskell's type system is based on. This will present the typing relation and, presumably, guide the reader in proving that certain terms have certain types.

Comment: Based on your post, I'm very sure that I can't handle a short introduction to the polymorphic λ-calculus. Nevertheless, thanks for the answer.

Comment: I don't think that's true. I think you'd find a well-done introduction surprisingly accessible.

Answer (score 1):

In an attempt to win the brevity contest:

Type signatures specify the types for the inputs (arguments) of a function, and for the value that the function returns.
So the number of items in a function's type signature is (n + 1), where n is the number of arguments that the function takes.

Comment: Yes. I very much misunderstood Haskell's type signatures. I thought they were doing something much more sophisticated. Thanks.